# Search in webpage using selenium python

Tags: python, forms, selenium, fill

I am using the webpage "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene" to search for info on genes. Typically, I insert the Gene_ID value in the text box and search manually.
Since I have a large number of genes to test for, I want to use selenium with python to automate the search.
I am wondering what exactly is the code to do it.
I have come so far as opening the safari browser and getting to the webpage.
I need to know how to insert gene_ID value into the text box and search.
What is the way to know the keyword to recognize the specific text box.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a unique locator to interact with a webelement in Selenium. In this case you are lucky because on the textbox there is a unique Id 'term'.

To check this you can use for instance Chrome Developertools. Point your mouse on the textbox of your page, right click and choose 'Inspect'. Use the search window of Chrome Developer Tools to check that a locator is unique.

[image]

The code to send your Gene_ID to the textbox will be:

```
geneTextBox = driver.find_element_by_id("term")
geneTextBox.send_keys("some_gene_id")
geneTextBox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for and it worked.